# Root Build Failed using CMake with Visual Studio 14 giving error Cannot evaluate the item metadata “%(FullPath)”

Tags: git, visual-studio, cmake, root-framework, cmake-gui

I am trying to configure my Visual Studio 14 with cmake but after this command `$ cmake -G "Visual Studio 14 2015"`. It shows this error message `BUILD FAILED`. I don't figure it out why the build failed with error message `Cannot evaluate the item metadata "%(FullPath)"`. I don't understand how to correct that, help needed quickly!!

```
ASHWANI KUMAR@ASHWANI MINGW64 /e/Study/GSoC'18/CERN-HSF/ROOT/root (master)

$ cmake -G "Visual Studio 14 2015"
-- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.0.24215.1
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.0.24215.1
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin/cl.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin/cl.exe -- broken
CMake Error at E:/Study/GSoC'18/CERN-HSF/ROOT/CMake/share/cmake-3.11/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:52 (message):
  The C compiler

    "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin/cl.exe"

  is not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

    Change Dir: E:/Study/GSoC'18/CERN-HSF/ROOT/root/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

    Run Build Command:"C:/Program Files (x86)/MSBuild/14.0/bin/MSBuild.exe" "cmTC_bfc97.vcxproj" "/p:Configuration=Debug" "/p:VisualStudioVersion=14.0"
    Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 14.0.25420.1
    Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

    Build started 3/10/2018 7:14:11 PM.
    Project "E:\Study\GSoC'18\CERN-HSF\ROOT\root\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_bfc97.vcxproj" on node 1 (default targets).
    C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(5121,7): error MSB4023: Cannot evaluate the item metadata "%(FullPath)". The item metadata "%(FullPath)" cannot be applied to the path "@(_DebugSymbolsInter mediatePath->'E:\Study\GSoC'18\CERN-HSF\ROOT\root\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\Debug\%(Filename)%(Extension)')". Illegal characters in path. [E:\Study\GSoC'18\CERN-HSF\ROOT\root\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_bfc97.vcxproj]
    Done Building Project "E:\Study\GSoC'18\CERN-HSF\ROOT\root\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_bfc97.vcxproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.

    Build FAILED.

    "E:\Study\GSoC'18\CERN-HSF\ROOT\root\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_bfc97.vcxproj"(default target) (1) ->
      C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(5121,7): error MSB4023: Cannot evaluate the item metadata "%(FullPath)". 
The item metadata "%(FullPath)" cannot be applied to the path "@(_DebugSymbolsIntermediatePath->'E:\Study\GSoC'18\CERN-HSF\ROOT\root\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\Debug\%(Filename)%(Extension)')". Illegal characters in path. [E:\Study\GSoC'18\CERN-HSF\ROOT\root\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_bfc97.vcxproj]

            0 Warning(s)
            1 Error(s)

        Time Elapsed 00:00:00.28
```

Answer (score 0):

Which version of ROOT are you trying to compile?
FYI, ROOT 6 (git master) requires Visual Studio 2017, and ROOT 5 requires at most Visual Studio 2013

Cheers, Bertrand.

Comment: I directly clone the root git repo using this command  `$ git clone https://github.com/root-project/root.git` and I didn't the command to check the root version through git

Comment: So for the master branch (the one you got by default), you need VS 2017. Otherwise you have to checkout the v5-34-00-patches branch (or a tagged version), but then you need VS 2013...

Comment: I also tried again to build Root by using VS 2017. But it Failed again.   `$ cmake -G "Visual Studio 15 2017"`
ERROR: The Platform for project 'VCTargetsPath.vcxproj' is invalid.  Platform='Visual Studio'. You may be seeing this message because you are trying to build a project without a solution file, and have specified a non-default Platform that doesn't exist for this project.

Comment: I think I am missing some components or any other thing. I will try again by Repairing my Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: I checked my cmake version `$ cmake --version` 
   `cmake version 3.11.0-rc3`